# SharePoint Health Analyzer doesn't refresh

Tags: central-administration, health-analyzer

I'm trying to fix some issues that I found on the SharePoint Health Analyzer. However when I solve (or at least try to solve) one of them and I click **Reanalyze Now**, nothing happens. By this I mean that even if the error still exists, the Modified date for that item is unchanged in the **Review problems and solutions** page.

I have solved a couple of issues that were pretty straightforward, and after reanalyzing them, still nothing changed. I would accept that my soluton was not correct, but the fact that the Modified date doesn't change leads me to think that the reanalyzing button is not working properly.

Is there a way to force the SharePoint Health Analyzer to refresh all of its items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to resolve these particular ones is to delete the health alert from the list and then [force the Health Analyzer Rules to run](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/force-run-sharepoint-health-analyzer-jobs-ondemand.html).

```
$TimerJobName = "Health Analysis Job"
$TimerJobs = Get-SPTimerJob | where { $_.DisplayName -match $TimerJobName}

foreach($TimerJob in $TimerJobs) 
{
    Write-Host "Running:" $TimerJob.DisplayName
    $TimerJob.RunNow()
 }
```